# Is there a way to grab data from QLineedit in password mode?

Tags: qt, memory

So I need to now how safe the QLineedit is for inputting passwords. I made a simple window with a single lineedit set into password echo mode. Let's say I types some word there. Now I need to somehow grab this word from the program's memory and monitor it (for wxample to see if it's still there after I cleared the edit or typed another word). However when I used the mmory inspectors like CheatEngine or GameConqueror their outputs didn't have this word. (And when I set the some internal variable in the program it was in both outputs allright)

Am I doing something wrong or does it mean that QLineEdit is secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It is not secure***, and it's not meant to be.

The data is there and also *extremely easy* to reach (you're probably not seeing it because of the UTF-16 encoding, but just try GammaRay against any Qt application and you'll see marvels).

I'm also wondering about your definition of "secure". Like anything else in computing: **if you let an attacker get too close, you'll lose.** End of the story.

If you're fighting against an attacker with capabilities of inspect your application's memory, there's almost nothing you can do to prevent them to eavesdrop to anything that goes on in your application, including processing the individual keypresses when you type the password.

Comment: By "secure" I meant "is not in memory after the contents of the edit are cleared" (I'm aware of undo-stack and I heard there are meant to clear it too).Obviously I don't think I can keep the password safe in the edit, I just want it as as reference. I have troubles using Gammaray as it crashes any app I run with it for some reason

Comment: I poked around a bit and confirmed what you said. Oh well, I'll try to solve at least dome of the issies. Thanks!